# Display product variations in shop page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Is it possible somehow to display all my product variations for one attribute on the shop page? Example: I have 1 T-Shirt with 2 variations 1 blue and 1 red. I need both blue and red to be displayed on the shop page as if they were separate products.

Comment: Why use product variations if you want the products to display as their own entity, just create two different products?

Comment: because then I won't have the attribute swatches in the product so I can jump from one color to the other.